# Sequence of button press in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, sequence

I have multiple buttons in my WinForm. A random sequence is chosen and the buttons have to be pressed in that sequence.

How do i detect If the sequence was broken i.e. the buttons were not clicked in the proper order?

The point is that i want to know which button was pressed after a certain button was pressed

```
Dim clicked As Boolean = False 
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
   clicked = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: I cannot find any logic to do this  but was trying something like this:


    Dim clicked As Boolean = False
 

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    clicked = True

    End Sub

Comment: you will need more than a clicked flag...you need to collect something to identify WHICH button was clicked and simply save that as part of the series.  Then compare it to the desired series order - either as soon as one is out of order or at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make all the buttons fire the same handler and append the Text() property to a String:

```
Private sequence As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click, Button5.Click, _
    Button6.Click, Button7.Click, Button8.Click, Button9.Click, Button0.Click

    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    sequence = sequence & btn.Text

    ' ... possibly do something with "sequence" ...

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

You'll need to add 10 buttons (in this case), and enter the numbers 1 to 10 in the tag properties for them...

**EDIT:** A smarter way ;-)

```
Dim lstButtonOrder As New List(Of Integer)
Dim lstMyRandomArray As New List(Of Integer)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    SetupArray()

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click,
                                                                        Button4.Click, Button5.Click, Button6.Click,
                                                                        Button7.Click, Button8.Click, Button9.Click, Button10.Click
    Dim butPressed As Button = TryCast(sender, Button)

    lstButtonOrder.Add(butPressed.Tag)

    If lstButtonOrder.Count = lstMyRandomArray.Count Then

        If Enumerable.SequenceEqual(lstButtonOrder, lstMyRandomArray) = True Then

            MsgBox("Well Done!")

        Else

            MsgBox("You Fail")

        End If

        SetupArray()

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SetupArray()
    Dim rnd = New Random
    lstMyRandomArray = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).OrderBy(Function(n) rnd.Next).ToList

    lblOrder.Text = "Please hit the buttons in this order..." & vbCrLf

    lstMyRandomArray.ToList().ForEach(Sub(x)
                                          lblOrder.Text &= x.ToString & " "
                                      End Sub)

    lstButtonOrder.Clear()

End Sub
```

Of course, I could've just parsed the name here, but I prefer using the tag property...

Comment: Is `arrArray` used anywhere here?

Comment: Yeah, I'm randomizing it in the SetupArray routine.I probably could've gotten away with 1 single array, but I fancied 2...

Comment: But you’re assigning that to `MyRandomArray`. Why not use `Enumerable.Range`?

Comment: You're right of course, however I didn't concentrate so much on generating the random array to be fair, as the OP was interested in checking which buttons had been pressed...

Answer (score 0):

I’d keep an array of buttons:

```
Private buttons() As Button = { Me.Button1, Me.Button2, Me.Button3, … }
```

You can make a handler:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' TODO
End Sub
```

Add the handlers to the buttons in `New()`:

```
Public Sub New()
    Me.InitializeComponent()

    For Each b In buttons
        AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
    Next
End Sub
```

After (or before) doing that, randomize `buttons`. Then keep track of the next one you expect the user to click:

```
Private currentButton As Integer = 0
```

In the handler, check:

```
If sender Is buttons(currentButton) Then
    ' Move to the next button
    currentButton += 1

    ' Was that the end of them?
    If currentButton = buttons.Length Then
        ' All buttons were pressed in the right order
    End If
Else
    ' Wrong!
End If
```

You could use a list, but you don’t really need to keep track of each button pressed if you know they match an order you already have.